# My .msi file installer during installation ask to close currently run console application or windows service

Tags: c#, .net, windows, service

I am trying through my console application or windows service to run the batch. Into batch I write commands which run my Setup.msi and create InstallLogFile.

1. Trying with console application. Problem arises when the Setup.msi is run and pop up me with "The 'MyConsoleApplication' should be closed before continuing the install". And I have option to check Automatically close applications and attempt to restart them after setup is complete.
2. Trying with starting my created Windows Service. Here is the thing little bit complicated cause after the Setup.msi is run, I don't see any pop up message, just through the log I find that my service is Stopped (probably my Setup.msi requires like in 1. case but I have no idea why) and after installation, service again Started and do the whole logic again, which I want to avoid.

   - Setup.msi is created via Wix Toolset
   - Setup.msi in both cases automatically downloaded from Dropbox via Web Client (code write in C#)

First in OnStart method of the windows service I called Update() in separate thread method which handle whole process.

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Task.Run(() => 
            {
                try
                {                        
                    Update();                      
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
                finally
                {

                }
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

I am not including whole code, just logic without log information.

In update method some of the core logic is:
1. Download the Setup.msi
2. Close process and stop some services
3. Start process which runs .bat with code which starts Setup.msi installation

```
public void Update()
    {
        var downloadLink = @"someLinkOnDropbox";

        // try to download
        try
        {
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {                   
                client.DownloadFile(downloadLink, myDirLocation);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {            

            return;
        }            

        while (ProcessIsRunning("someProcess") || ServiceIsRunning("someService1") || ServiceIsRunning("someService2") || ServiceIsRunning("someService3"))
        {
            // try to terminate process
            StopProcess("someProcess");

            // try to stop the service
            StopService("someService1");
            StopService("someService2");
            StopService("someService3");                
        }

        // wait 5 sec process and services are stopped
        Thread.Sleep(5000);

        // path to the my .bat file on D: disc which run Setup.msi (also downloaded on my D: disc)
        const string path = @"somePath";
        const string fileName = @"batName.bat";
        const string workingDirectory = @"myDir";

        try
        {          
            Task.Run(() => 
            {
            StartProcess(path, fileName, workingDirectory);
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

Also, methods StopProcess, StopService, ProcessIsRunning and ServiceIsRunning are custom made and working fine in that point I have no problems.

Method StartProcess is below:

```
public void StartProcess(string path, string fileName, string workingDirectory)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(path)
        {
            FileName = fileName,
            WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory,
            UseShellExecute = true,
            CreateNoWindow = false,
            WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
        };

        //  Try to start the process.
        try
        {
            Process p = new Process {StartInfo = psi};
            p.Start();
            Log.Instance.Warn($"Process started");
            p.WaitForExit();
            Log.Instance.Warn($"Process finished");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

Code which is in .bat file:
msiexec /i Setup.msi /l*v SetupInstall.log INSTALL_SETTINGS_FOR="deviceID"

Comment: It is not clear what you're actually asking. Are you trying to make your application to update itself?

Comment: Not trying to update itself,
-the point is that I Created Windows Service.
-This windows service when started, downolad Setup.msi from dropbox
- then from the same windows service I run new process which runs .batch file. 
- this .batch file run Setup.msi which will install some application.

But during this installation process my windows service is stopped, cause Setup.msi requires that, why I don't know? After it stopped and installation is completed, windows service is started again, and that is the case I want to avoid.

Comment: Show us some code, please. How exactly do you launch your .bat? How exactly do you trigger an installation of .msi?

Comment: @rs232 Please, find some code in edited question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the thing what makes me problem with my service.

My application which I want to update via MyService are on the same location and used some same files. So during update process when MyService run it through the batch, installation requires to stop service cause service used some files which need to be updated, cause also application uses it.

Solution was to move Service installation location into the new dir. Something like
D:\MyApp for the app, and
D:\MyApp\MyService for the service, 
and in this case shared files between MyApp and MyService can be updated in MyApp without requirement from MyApp to stop MyService.